# NavigationLink doesn't work in nested ScrollView after EnvironmentObject update from network request

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two tabs for navigationView, Dashboard and Userscreen.

Userscreen is used for fetching user information through network request, and dashboard is showing information through network request based on user information, hense user information is the environment object here.

After update user information I can view dashboard properties but click on navigation link is not working.
After doing some testing, I found that the navigation link(showing based on user info) under ScrollView -> ScrollView(.horizontal) -> NavigationLink is not working, but navigation link(showing based on user info) under VStack -> ScrollView(.horizontal) -> NavigationLink performs well.

I wonder if I was missing something on the implementation or may I ask is it an existing bug for XCode?

Edit: Updated code

Edit again: Please refer to @workingdog solution below, the whole problem is just caused by a simple silly mistake, which is not declare the right state/environment object.

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher
import Alamofire

struct ExampleView: View {
@StateObject var userInfoManager = UserInfoManagerExample()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView (){
            DashboardScreenExample()
                .environmentObject(userInfoManager)
                .tabItem{
                    Text("Dashboard")
                }
            LoginScreenExample()
                .environmentObject(userInfoManager)
                .tabItem{
                    Text("UpdateInfo")
                }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
}

struct DashboardScreenExample: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userInfoManager : UserInfoManagerExample
@State var please : Bool = false

init(){
   Theme.navigationBarColors(background: UIColor(viewProperties.themered), titleColor: .white)
}

var viewProperties = ViewProperties()

var body: some View {
    if(userInfoManager.shouldShowDashboard){
        ScrollView{//Switch this ScrollView to VStack make Navigation Link work again
            //I had other screens too, but screen below is the one causing problem
            DashboardContentExample()
        }
    }else{
        ProgressView().onAppear{userInfoManager.shouldShowDashboard = true}
    }
}
}

struct DashboardContentExample: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userInfoManager : UserInfoManagerExample
@ObservedObject var dashboardList = DashboardConfigRequestExample()

func loadRequest(){
    dashboardList.loadData(passedLanguage: userInfoManager.preferenceLangauge)
}

//View start from here
var body: some View {
    if(dashboardList.dashboardConfig.count == 0){
        ProgressView()
            .onAppear{
                loadRequest()
            }
    }else{
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            LazyHStack{
                //Here is the NavigationLink not working
                NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()){
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct LoginScreenExample: View {

let usernameLoginRequest = UsernameLoginRequestExample()
@EnvironmentObject var userInfoManager : UserInfoManagerExample
@State var loginClicked : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
        if(userInfoManager.isLogin){
            Text("You have logged in.")
                .onAppear{
                    loginClicked = false
                }
        }
        else{
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    //the username and password had to be entered
                    Button(action:{clickLogin(forUsername: "iamusername", andPassword: "iampassword")}){
                        Text("Sign In")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                if(loginClicked){
                    ProgressView()
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

func clickLogin(forUsername: String, andPassword: String){
    loginClicked.toggle()
    usernameLoginRequest.loadData(forUsername: forUsername, andPassword: andPassword, andUserInfo: userInfoManager)
}
}

class UserInfoManagerExample : ObservableObject{

@Published var isLogin: Bool = false
@Published var username: String = ""
@Published var password: String = ""
@Published var preferenceLangauge: String = "en"
@Published var shouldShowDashboard = true

init(){
}

func updateCredential(forUsername: String, andPassword: String){
    username = forUsername
    password = andPassword
}
}

struct UsernameLoginRequestExample{

func loadData(forUsername: String, andPassword: String, andUserInfo: UserInfoManagerExample){
    let request_url = "This is the request url"
    let request_parameters = getUsernameLoginParameter(withUsername: forUsername, andPassword: andPassword)
    
    AF
    .request(request_url, method: .post, parameters: request_parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ).responseJSON{
        responses
        in
        debugPrint(responses)
        
        switch responses.result{
        case .success:
            do {
                andUserInfo.shouldShowDashboard = false
                andUserInfo.updateCredential(forUsername: forUsername, andPassword: andPassword)
                andUserInfo.isLogin = true
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func getUsernameLoginParameter(withUsername : String, andPassword : String) -> [String : String]{
    var parameters : [String : String] = [String : String]()
    parameters.updateValue(withUsername, forKey: "username")
    parameters.updateValue(andPassword, forKey: "password")
    
    var device_id : String
    
    if(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor != nil){
        device_id = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
    }else{
        device_id = ""
    }
    
    parameters.updateValue(device_id, forKey:"device_id")
    
    return parameters
}
}

class DashboardConfigRequestExample : ObservableObject{
@Published var dashboardConfig = [DashboardConfigExample]()

func loadData(passedLanguage : String){
    let request_url = "This is request url"
          
    let request_parameters = getDashboardConfigParameter(passedLanguage: passedLanguage)
    
    AF
    .request(request_url, method:.post, parameters: request_parameters)
    .responseJSON{
        
        responses in
        
        switch responses.result {
            case .success:
                guard
                    let data = responses.data
                else { return }
                do {
                    let configResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(DashboardConfigDataExample.self, from: data)
                        self.dashboardConfig = configResponse.list ?? []
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
        }
    }
}

func getDashboardConfigParameter(passedLanguage: String) -> [String:String]{
    var parameters : [String:String] = [String:String]()
    parameters.updateValue(passedLanguage, forKey: "language")
    return parameters
}
}

struct DashboardConfigDataExample : Decodable{
public var status: String?
public var list: [DashboardConfigExample]?
}

struct DashboardConfigExample: Encodable & Codable {
let background_image: String?
let background_color: String?
}
```

Comment: your code seems to work for me in my tests. Clicking on the `NavigationLinks` works.
On macos 12.1-beta, using xcode 13.2-beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my codes is working if `@Published var` is updated without network request.
There are two comments in the code which would perform asynchronous network request from my backend, in turn updating the environment object, screen involving `NavigationLinks` need to be updated again, then the `NavigationLinks` would not work after the requests. 
But replacing `ScrollView` with `VStack` somehow make the `NavigationLinks` works.

Comment: So the code you are showing us is not the code that gives you any problems. Can you show us the code that can replicate your problem?

Comment: I had changed the code, but removed network request parameter and url, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
@ObservedObject var infoRequest = InfoRequest()
```

in `Dashboard` with

```
@StateObject var infoRequest = InfoRequest()
```

EDIT1: in light of the new code.

Try moving `@ObservedObject var dashboardList = DashboardConfigRequestExample()` of `DashboardContentExample`
into `ExampleView` as `@StateObject`. Something like the following example code:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @StateObject var userInfoManager = UserInfoManagerExample()
    @StateObject var dashboardList = DashboardConfigRequestExample()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView (){
                DashboardScreenExample().tabItem{ Text("Dashboard")}
                LoginScreenExample().tabItem{ Text("UpdateInfo")}
            }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .environmentObject(userInfoManager)  // <-- here
        .environmentObject(dashboardList)    // <-- here
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DashboardContentExample: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfoManager : UserInfoManagerExample
    @EnvironmentObject var dashboardList: DashboardConfigRequestExample  // <-- here
    
    func loadRequest(){
        dashboardList.loadData(passedLanguage: userInfoManager.preferenceLangauge)
    }
    
    //View start from here
    var body: some View {
        if(dashboardList.dashboardConfig.count == 0){
            ProgressView()
                .onAppear{
                    loadRequest()
                }
        }else{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                LazyHStack{
                    //Here is the NavigationLink not working
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello destination")){  // <-- here for testing
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had changed it, it seems the navigation link is still not working. By the way, I had edit the codes to the ones really causing me problem, thank you for helping out @workingdog !!

Comment: updated my answer in light of your new code.

Comment: Sorry for replying late @workingdog ... The navigation links is not working even after I added a new `@stateobject` and `@environmentobject` according to the updated answer, but thanks anyway for lending a help!

But there is a weird behavior for the `navigation links` is that, they are not response on click, but after switch tab, the screen from links before would pop out immediately.

Comment: It turns out to be I put the environmentobject on the wrong screen, thank you so much!